# Process Builder - Immediate Actions creating two tasks instead of one?

Tags: process-builder

On my Process Builder my new decision node is an OR filter on two similar Lead Source values, this is working correctly.

The immediate action is to create a Task.

The result is two tasks appear in the Lead record Activity.

I have tried the recursive switch is on the decision node with no effect.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. You're going to need to look at the Debug Log to see if the Process Builder gets invoked twice, perhaps because of other automations that cause the Lead to be updated.

You should also check the Advanced Option settings for the Decision Block to see if the PB is only triggered if the decision block's fields _have changed in value_

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I was testing recursion on the decision node.  The recursion on the PB itself for the object needed to be disabled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).